# 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a project that I want to refresh a bit, but it is no longer working as it once did.

It supports multiple languages (English, French, etc.), but I am now getting the following error:
'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll at run time when it attempts to change languages cultures.

This happens when it and its language res files / .dlls are built with the dot net framework version 3.5.

This does not happen if I change the language res files / .dlls to be built with the 4.5 dot net framework.

The language are res files are build as x86, I've tried both x86 and anycpu for the project - in various combinations but, again, it only works at runtime when using the dot net framework 4.5.

The error gets thrown with this code:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(My.Settings.Language)
```

I would like to use the dot net framework 3.5 for better OS backwards compatibility.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how far back do you have to go? NET 4.0 runs on XP

Comment: I am sure, you messed up your project configurations. Use `corflags.exe` to check all your DLLs build architecture.

Comment: I've never used corflags before, but thanks for that I did some reading, tested it, but sadly everything was built as expected ...

Comment: Testing with dot net 4.0 worked well, I will go that route ... thanks for the idea Plutonix !

Answer (score 4):

The BadImageFormatException was usually thrown, if you use wrong x86 or x64 builds. If you switch to x86, have you done this for all the depend sources? Or have done this only for the starting project?

Comment: Yes, that was my first suspicion too, I tried switching (for example) both the program itself, and the generated res / .dlls to x86 but that didn't resolve the issue for dot net 3.5.